# Hide DIV when successfully submitted

Tags: php, forms

I have this form which is working perfectly. However, I want to hide the form when it is submitted. Basically, I would like to hide the entire div starting with this: `<div class="HideSuccess">` when it is successfully submitted or when the form is submitted with/without error.

How do I go about this?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $fp = fopen("data.txt","a");
    if (!$fp) {
        echo 'Error!';
        exit;
    }
    if (@fwrite($fp, $Fname.'|'.$Email."\n")) {
        echo '<p class="thanks">Success<p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Error!</p>';
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
<div class="HideSuccess">
    <form name="input" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Full Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Full Name'" required />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Email'" required />
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are submitting the form on the same page, this might work for you.
This will hide the div if there's a POST data on page load

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $Fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $fp = fopen("data.txt","a");
    if(!$fp) {
        echo 'Error!';
        exit;
    }
    if(@fwrite($fp, $Fname.'|'.$Email."\n")){
        echo '<p class="thanks">Success<p>';
    }else{
        echo '<p>Error!</p>';
    }
    fclose($fp);
else: ?>
<div class="HideSuccess">
    <form name="input" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Full Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Full Name'" required />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Email'" required />
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: Adding full code as requested

Comment: I'm not sure how to embed the php code with your code. Could you kindly complete it? The code given in the question is the complete code and it's on the same page.

Comment: @ElaineByene , there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or pure javascript for remove/hide block dynamically.

But you must understand cause after real form submit your page reload. And for this case you can use ajax.

For example:

Add identificator for your form:

```
<form id="my-form" ...
```

And write something like:

```
var
    myForm        = $('#my-form'),
    myFormSuccess = myForm.closest('.HideSuccess');

myForm.on('submit', function() {
    $.post(myForm.attr('action'), myForm.serialize(), function() {
        myFormSuccess.slideUp(500);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The form stop working after I did this and I'm using the latest version of jQuery :(